# boost::asio::post: calling a function in lambda vs inline definition

Tags: c++, post, boost-asio

I am experimenting with the `boost::asio::thread_pool` and the `boost::asio::post()` function.
In my program, which does matrix multiplication, I use [the third overload](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/post/overload3.html) of the function:

```cpp
decltype (auto) matrix_multiplication (const matrix& A, const matrix& B)
{
  
  // ...

  const auto CPU_CORES{std::thread::hardware_concurrency ()};
  boost::asio::thread_pool pool{CPU_CORES};

  for (auto row_a{0u}; row_a < A_ROWS; ++row_a)
    {
      for (auto col_b{0u}; col_b < B_COLS; ++col_b)
        {
          // VERSION 1
          boost::asio::post (pool, [&A, &B, &result, row_a, col_b] ()
          {
            calculate_result_cell (A, B, row_a, col_b,
                                   result[row_a][col_b]);
          });

          // VERSION 2
          boost::asio::post (pool, [&A, &B, &result, row_a, col_b] ()
          {
            result[row_a][col_b] = 0;
            for (auto inner{0u}; inner < B.size (); ++inner)
              {
                result[row_a][col_b] += A[row_a][inner] * B[inner][col_b];
              }
          });
        }
    }

  // ...
}
```

where `calculate_result_cell` does the same as in VERSION 2:

```cpp
decltype (auto) calculate_result_cell (const matrix& A, const matrix& B,
                                       int row, int col, int& res)
{
  res = 0;

  for (auto inner{0u}; inner < B.size (); ++inner)
    {
      res += A[row][inner] * B[inner][col];
    }
}
```

When I tested both versions as part of a small benchmark (calling each version five times with a 1'000 by 1'000 matrix), VERSION 2 takes significantly (~20%) longer. The reason I tried VERSION 2 in the first place was in hope of saving the function call. But it is not doing what I expected it to.

What is the difference between these two versions? Why the difference in runtime?

Comment: a side remark for style: `dectype (auto)` is a very way to spell `void`

Comment: I think you need to supply the test code and compiler/flags used for us to say something. My guess is your function doesn't get inlined. Ideas: mark it inline static, enable LTO